# MvvmCross Windows Phone 8.1 bind list selection to command, compilation failure

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-runtime, mvvmcross

I've the following error:

> Object of type Windows.UI.Xml.Controls.ListView cannot be converted to type System.Windows.DependencyObject

Due to the following code:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Cases}" IsItemClickEnabled="False" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowCaseCommand, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

I added EventTrigger to the namespace like so:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

I added Interaction to the project by adding a reference manually from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.5\Libraries\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`.

Of course removing the `<i:Interaction.Triggers>` block eliminates the error but I need to bind selection to a command, like I do in UIKit and Android.

So – what manner of deviltry is this?

Comment: Why can't you just bind SelectedItem to a property in your ViewModel?

Comment: If I have a setter call ShowViewModel than the ViewModel has a less intuitive interface. It seems the Daily Dilbert example uses ItemSelectedCommand in iOS but not Windows Store. If I figure out why the trigger doesn't work I'll post the answer here but I probably will wind up bodging the core library somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this code is not compatible with Windows Phone 8.1.

The list view needs to be set up like so:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Cases}"  IsItemClickEnabled="False" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowCaseCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```

One needs to add a reference to the `Behaviors` library, not Windows.Interaction.

The code above requires the following attributes on the root node:

```
xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

**This leads to another problem;** while it will be bound to ShowCaseCommand, it will pass in instance of SelectionChangedEventArgs, rather than the selected list item.

We solve this with `CommandParameter`.

We add an attribute to the `ListView`, like so – `<ListView Name='listView' ...` – and this name allows us to refer to it later:

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowCaseCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=SelectedItem}" />
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

By specifying the command parameter like this, we can pass the selected item as the parameter, making it compatible with the same sort of selection command one uses in iOS.